# jQuery .hide for dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I'm not a great programmer, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this issue.  I have the following code:

```
     jQuery('.wpdm-cat-link').click(function(){
     jQuery('#wpdm-downloads').prepend('<div class="loading">Loading1...</div>').load('<?php echo home_url('/?wpdmtask=get_downloads&category=');?>'+this.rel);
     jQuery('.dropdown-menu').hide();
         return false;
     });
```

It fires a dropdown menu.  Once the menu option is selected, it closes the drop down menu and will not allow it to be opened in the same session.  I'm assuming that's what

```
    jquery('.dropdown-menu').hide();
```

is doing.  Could another command be stacked on top of this to allow it to open again?  When an option is selected, it's using AJAX to load some content beneath the menu.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just comment this line having ".hide()" call and menu will be available for opening again.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('.dropdown-menu').show();
```

you can use `show();` function

Comment: There are two drop down menus next to each other.  Using .show leaves the current drop down open, then automatically opens up the other one.

Comment: can you add html code to your question? or create jsfiddle